# Vibration of annular sector plate

Tags: vibration

The deflection of the sector is assumed in the following form
[image: deflection]
But I don't know why they assumed G(θ) in the following form [image: G(θ)] 
and how to compute η.Can somebody help me? Thanks.

Comment: The cos and sin terms represent standing waves, and I think the cosh and sinh terms represent decay at free and clamped edges.  Your textbook should have an explanation.

Answer (score 1):

The governing equation for free vibrations of a circular plate is [(see Wikipedia article on vibrating Kirchhoff plates)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vibration_of_plates#Circular_plates)
$$
\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial }{\partial r}\left[r \frac{\partial }{\partial r}\left\{\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial }{\partial r}\left(r \frac{\partial w}{\partial r}\right)\right\}\right] = -\frac{2\rho h}{D}\frac{\partial^2 w}{\partial t^2}\,.
$$
Separation of variables leads to a general solution of the form
$$ 
w(r,t) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty C_n\left[J_0(\lambda_n r) - \frac{J_0(\lambda_n a)}{I_0(\lambda_n a)}I_0(\lambda_n r)\right]
    [A_n e^{i\omega_n t} + B_n e^{-i\omega_n t}] \,.
$$
The term
$$
  A_n e^{i\omega_n t} + B_n e^{-i\omega_n t}
$$
can be expressed as a sum of sine, cosines, and hyperbolic sines and cosines when we take the real part of $w$.  That's why the expression for $G(\theta)$ in your book has that form.

For a annular sector of a circular plate, things are a bit more complicated and you will have to do the algebra yourself (or look it up from a book) to find out what $\eta$ is.

P.S.  The correct term for these orthogonal functions is *basis* functions (and not *basic* functions) - see [Wikipedia basis function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basis_function).

Answer (score 0):

Biswajit covered most of it, but to build on his answer a little: when you are solving these types of problems, your answer has to satisfy both the partial differential equation and the boundary conditions.  $G(\theta)$ as given in your question is the most general solution to the PDE.  But it will not satisfy the boundary condition for all values of $\eta$, A, B, C, and D.  e.g. a clamped boundary at 0 would be expressed as $G(0)=0$, $G'(0)=0$. If you picked $A=B=D=0$, and $C=1$, you can see that this does not satisfy the boundary conditions, because $cos(0)=1$.  But there is some other combination of parameters that will satisfy it.  To solve for the 4 unknowns, you will need to apply 4 boundary conditions, 2 at each end of your sector.